# AWS Datapipeline - import randomly named files in a s3 bucket to Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-data-pipeline

I have a use case where new files can show up in a s3 folder at any time and we would like to import them in Redshift via the RedshiftCopyActivity. I have a pipeline setup where we can move data from s3 to Redshift - but with files that are specifically named. However, in this case the file names can be random. I am thinking of something like

- Say we have a s3 folder s3://toProcess
- Every hour the data pipeline job checks if there are new files in s3://toProcess
- If there are then these are processed and deleted (so it doesn't process them in next hour)

Any thoughts on how to get this done?

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new [AWS Data Pipeline](https://aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/) there is an option to use a predefined template. For what you need the [Load Data from S3 Into Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/dp-template-s3redshift.html) Template should get you most of the way there. You will need to add an Activity that looks something like what is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26514404/delete-s3-files-from-a-pipeline-aws) to delete those files.